# Vuetify : How to get the value of a prefix from a text field

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a form in my page with various text fields, on one of them I put a prefix because I want the value entered to always start with the same 5 letters.

I was able to get my value from the text field to my save method but not the prefix and I can't add it manually while saving because the value will depend on what type the user choses, I will try to explain this :

- If the user choses Type A there will be no prefix and the value will be saved as it is entered by the user.
- If the user choses Type B there will be a prefix in the text field and the value will be saved with prefix + value entered by the user.

Here's the code I have for now :
Both my text fields depending on which type the user choses :

```
  <v-col v-show="type === 'TypeA'">
    <v-text-field
      v-model="id"
      clearable
      required
      light
      solo
      dense
      max-length="36"
      :rules="idRule"
    >
    </v-text-field>
  </v-col>
  <v-col v-show="type === 'TypeB'">
    <v-text-field
      v-model="id"
      clearable
      required
      light
      solo
      dense
      max-length="31"
      prefix="ABCDE"
      :rules="idRule"
    ></v-text-field
  ></v-col>
```

And this is what I do in my save method :

```
await this.$axios.$post(uri, {
  id: this.id,
});
```

I probably can get away with adding it later depending on which type is chosen but I want the user to see the prefix, so is there a way I can get the prefix from the text field directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the prefix was a variable, you could just add the prefix value to the `id` value when saving.  You also wouldn't need two different v-text-field components just to handle different prefixes since the prefix can be dynamically updated based on `type`.  A [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed) would probably be easiest.

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model="id"
  :prefix="prefix"
></v-text-field>
```

```js
computed: {
  prefix() {
    return this.type === 'TypeB' ? 'ABCDE' : ''
  },
},

...

save() {
  await this.$axios.$post(uri, {
    id: this.prefix + this.id,
  });
}
```

[demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)